# C++ getkey() and kbhit() acting on wrong window

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard

I am writing a microsoft windows program that starts in a console window and then spawns a separate gui window to do some directx rendering in.

I am trying to get the keyboard characters while the focus is on the directx window but when I type characters, getkey doesn't register that I hit anything.  After some messing around, I discovered that if I change focus to the console window after pressing a key in the directx window, my program registers the keyboard hit. Do I need some special initialization of the directx window to be able to capture the keyboard hits?

Comment: Use window messages instead of deprecated functions! Their purposes here are completely different. You own your GUI window, and thus can handle all input coming to it via the standard window messages.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect kbhit listens only on the console (stdin).

Call the [GetKeyboardState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646299%28VS.85%29.aspx) API to poll the keyboard state (on every frame) instead of using those other functions you referred to.  This will probably be what you want and will work fine.  It's what we used when I worked in a game studio.

If you want to be more event driven than polling, and you have a message pump (GetMessage/DispatchMessage loop), just can listen for some combination of [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932721.aspx), [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and [WM_KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on the window handle (hwnd) of your DirectX window.

And if you need focus gain/loss detection, look for [WM_SETFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[WM_KILLFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or just use [GetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)().